# QGIS ordering categorized styling doesn't work

Tags: qgis, style

I would like to have my categorized styling in the correct order.

When I select the "Categorized" style option, QGIS orders it quite randomly. The effect is next visible on our map. Since you don't have overlays that's fine. Otherwise, there is a problem, which I have now. I have two items appearing in the same place, and which style category is different. I used the offset option, but the best will be to show the bottom one (turquoise) on the top.

[image]

I moved the `In-Line Splice Closures` value above the `Midspan OH` value in my categorized list, but it seems to not work unfortunately. Is there any smart solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Control feature rendering order` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#layer-rendering)) at the very bottom of the Layer Styling panel: Epxand `Layer Rendering`, check the box next to `Control feature rendering order`, click the `A/Z` icon and the define the field that defines the rendering order as well as ascending/descending.

If you need a custom order (not alphabetically), you might create a new attribute field for that purpose - like a field `rendering_order` with values from 1 to n.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For fine tuning of the rendering, you can use the `symbol level` and set the desired order. This setting, compared to @Babel easiest solution, lets you draw various part of a symbol at various zlevel (ex print polygon fill of a category below another one, but draw its boundary above it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used your solution and it doesn't work. Shall I use the attribute table for that?